# "The language attribute on the script element is obsolete. You can safely omit it."?

Tags: html, w3c-validation, script-element

According to the W3C validator, I am getting this error:

> The `language` attribute on the `script` element is obsolete. You can safely omit it.
>
> ```
> …uage="JavaScript" src="js/gen_validatorv31.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
> ```

How do I fix this?

I checked through the script and it should not be an issue.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/gen_validatorv31.js"
     language="JavaScript"></script>
```

You don't need to include redundant `language="JavaScript"`. Specifying just the `type` and `src` is valid, `language` is obsolete, remove it.

Comment: If you are using HTML5 `type="text/javascript"` is the default so you could leave that out too if you wanted. See http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/CR/scripting-1.html#attr-script-type