# closing the submenu on clicking the next menu

Tags: javascript, html, menubar

I have the following javascript :-

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
  function HideandUNhideObj(ThisObj){
  nav=document.getElementById(ThisObj).style
  if(nav.display=="none"){
  nav.display='block';
  }else{
  nav.display='none';
  }
  }
 </script>
```

And I have the following HTML code for the menus and sub menus

```
 <ul>
 <li><a href="#" onclick="HideandUNhideObj('div1');">Menu 1</a>
 <div style="display: none;" id="div1">
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Submenu 3</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Submenu 4</a></li>
   </ul>
  </div>
 </li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li><a href="#" onclick="HideandUNhideObj('div2');">Menu 2</a>
 <div style="display: none;" id="div2">
   <ul>
     <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
     <li><a href="#">Submenu 3</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">Submenu 4</a></li>
   </ul>
 </div>
 </li>
</ul>
```

But on one click makes a submenu appear and clicking it again hides it.

I need to hide the sub menus, when we click on the next menu. Only one Menu should open the sub menus in it.

Now, I can open two menus, having its sub menus in it, and on clicking the menu only, will hide those.

Please help.

The sample menu I created :-

[image]

Comment: u want wen Menu 1 is open then Menu2 must hide and vice-versa?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you have more than just 2 submenus, the @Ashish's answer is not very scalable.

I've played a little bit wit your code and got something like this http://jsfiddle.net/LfAbb/ :

```
function HideandUNhideObj(submenuId){
    hideAllSubmenus();
    showSubmenu(submenuId);
}

function hideAllSubmenus() {
    var submenus = document.getElementsByClassName("submenu");   
    for (var i = 0; i < submenus.length; ++i) {
        var submenu = submenus[i];
        hideSubmenu(submenu);            
    }
}

function hideSubmenu(elem) {
    elem.style.display = "none";
}

function showSubmenu(submenuId) {
    document.getElementById(submenuId).style.display = "block";
}
```

I changed the handler so it firstly closes all submenus, and then opens the necessary one.
Also consider using jQuery or similar library, if you work with JS a lot in your app - it will simplify things a lot.

P.S. Also you may consider refactoring your code:

1. Nowadays there is no need to use *language* attribute for *script* tag. [it's obsolete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10001983/the-language-attribute-on-the-script-element-is-obsolete-you-can-safely-omit-i)
2. use *var* when declare local variables. [explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1470488/difference-between-using-var-and-not-using-var-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

if u want wen Menu 1 is open then Menu2 must hide and vice-versa

```
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      //<![CDATA[
      function HideandUNhideObj(ThisObj){

            if(ThisObj == "div1")
            {
                var div = "div2";
            }
            else
            {
                var div = "div1";
            }

          nav=document.getElementById(ThisObj).style;
          if(nav.display=="none"){
          nav.display='block';
          document.getElementById(div).style.display = "none";
          }else{
          nav.display='none';
          document.getElementById(div).style.display = "block";
          }
      }
      //]]>
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

JAVA SCRIPT in :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 function hide(i)
 { 
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('subMenu');
    for(var k = 0; k < elements.length; k++){
        elements[k].style.display = 'none'; // Hide all elements.
    }
    $(i).show();
 }     

</script>
```

HTML in  :

```
<ul>
  <li><div>
      <a href="#" class="menu" onclick="hide(sub1);">Menu 1</a>
      <ul id="sub1" class="subMenu">
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li><div>
     <a href="#" class="menu" onclick="hide(sub2)">Menu 2</a>
     <ul id="sub2" class="subMenu">
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 3</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Submenu 4</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </li>
</ul>
```